# how to change page url and working same work on server side

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to change  page url just add query parameter in url all remove and work server side

this is my .htacess file but not working showing 404 error please clear my issue sorry for short description sir

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ course.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^course/([0-9]+)?$ course.php?id=$1 [NC]`

It will internally redirect
https://example.com/course/100
to
https://example.com/course.php?id=100
But the user will see/should use the first link.